# Link não funciona ao ser clicado

Tags: html, css, link

Tenho esse código de um menu e ao ser clicado no item Biografia o link não funciona:

```html
<ul id="ul-menu">
 <li class="li-menu"><a class="scroll" href="http://www.iracemafilha.com">HOME</a></li>
 <li class="li-menu"><a class="scroll" href="http://www.iracemafilha.com/biografia">BIOGRAFIA</a></li>
 <li class="li-menu"><a class="scroll" href="#discografia">DISCOGRAFIA</a></li>
 <li class="li-menu"><a class="scroll" href="#fotos">FOTOS</a></li>
 <li class="li-menu"><a class="scroll" href="#videos">VIDEOS</a></li>
 <li class="li-menu"><a class="scroll" href="#agenda">AGENDA</a></li>
 <li class="li-menu"><a class="scroll" href="#convite">CONVITE</a></li>
 <li class="li-menu"><a class="scroll" href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
</ul>
```

Código CSS:

```
#ul-menu {
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 25px;
   word-spacing: 50px;
}

.li-menu {
    display: inline;    
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
 }

.li-menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #483D45;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

Já coloquei o destino do link no "href" mas quando eu clico não vai.

Comment: Esse site `http://www.iracemafilha.com` está numa lista negra como site inseguro... podes dar mais detalhes que site é esse e quais os links que não funcionam?

Comment: Amigo, antes de fazer o site precisei da hospedagem pra criar uma página fake afim de estudos de uma disciplina "Desenvolvimento de Código Seguro" da Faculdade, porém já retirei todos os links e arquivos maliciosos, já enviei mensagem pro Google retirar o site da lista e fazer um novo scam mas ainda não responderem, eu terei que registrar um novo domínio .com.br, mas não se preocupe que não tem nada de malicioso no site, o problema é que o Google ainda não retirou o alerta mesmo retirando todos os arquivos maliciosos. O item iografia não vai para o destino http://www.iracemafilha.com/biografia

Comment: Testei no fiddle e funcionou ele redirecionou pra página na mesma aba, coloque soloque um taget="_blank" pra ver melhor o redirecionamento, tenha certeza que há um elemento com id igual aos href="#".

Comment: Ricardo, não estou utilizando mais a navegação por âncoras utilizando IDs, resolvi fazer as páginas individuais mesmo. Estou me referindo ao primeiro item de menu "Biografia", aqui ele não está redirecionando para o alvo.

Comment: O que tens na pasta `/biografia`? devia ser `biografia.html`? ou `.php`? ou talvez falte somente uma `/` para ser `http://www.iracemafilha.com/biografia/`. Eu não vou testar mais no seu site e não vejo como reproduzir este erro para poder ajudar mais.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `<head>` da página, tem um script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 200);
    });
});
```

O seu link tem a classe `scroll`, por isso está disparando o evento configurado em `$(".scroll").click`. O método `event.preventDefault()` interrompe a navegação do link. Para corrigir, remova o `preventDefault` ou remova a classe `scroll` do link.

Além disso, o script está dando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Comment: Marcus Vinicius, eu tinha realmente esquecido desse script, justo que eu até tinha desativado a navegação por âncoras na mesma página e esqueci do script. Vou testar.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado Marcus Vinicius, achei que por não estar utilizando o script ele seria inútil mesmo não tendo as ãncoras.